# php crawler(to crawl single website)

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, web-crawler

I'm working on crawler project and I need some help from you, this is my first project. The task is to fetch the data from 'http://justdial.com'. for example, I want to fetch the city name(bangalore), categoury(hotels), hotel name, address and phone number.

I have written a code to fetch the  tag content from its 'id', like I have fetched the address from this:

```
<?php

$url="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/hotels";  
$original_file = file_get_contents("$url");
$stripped_file = strip_tags($original_file, "<div>");

$newlines="'<div class=\"logoDesc\">(.*?)</div>'si";
$newlines=preg_replace('#<div(?:[^>]*)>.</div>#u','',$newlines);

preg_match_all("$newlines", $stripped_file, $matches);


//DEBUGGING

  //$matches[0] now contains the complete A tags; ex: <a href="link">text</a>
  //$matches[1] now contains only the HREFs in the A tags; ex: link

  header("Content-type: text/plain"); //Set the content type to plain text so the print below is easy to read!
 $path= ($matches);

 print_r($path); //View the array to see if it worked
?>
```

Now the problem is, I want to seperate the tags from the contents and store it in a database. And from database to the excel sheet. Please help me.

Comment: You mean `strip_tags()`?

Comment: What does path contain? Please show us a dump. Have you tried any database code yet? Is there a requirement to go from database -> excel, or can the excel sheet be generated at the same time? Does it have to be xls, or will csv suffice?

Comment: You mean [MySQL](http://php.net/mysqli) and [fputcsv](http://php.net/fputcsv) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using regex to parse HTML. You should be using something like [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php). Small example of it in use:

```
<?php
   $str = '<h1>T1</h1>Lorem ipsum.<h1>T2</h1>The quick red fox...<h1>T3</h1>... jumps over the lazy brown FROG';
   $DOM = new DOMDocument;
   $DOM->loadHTML($str);

   //get all H1
   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('h1');

   //display all H1 text
   for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: I have used the html parse to parse the content of the php. This is the code.

Comment: hello @wayne, I have included the html parser to parse the content of the php. I don't want to use the database, I would like to use notepad. As an page of 'justdial.com' runs the data must store in the notepad and then from notepad into excel sheet.